# Can the default value of a managed package global value set be changed in the subscriber org?

Tags: managed-package, picklist, global-picklist

We have a custom Global Value Set (AKA Picklist Value Set) for countries that will be in a managed package and it would be great if the default value could be changed after the package installation. (We would default it to "United States" but an org for e.g. the UK could have the default changed locally to "United Kingdom".)

Can that be changed locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

Here's an example where the managed package didn't set a default at all and I could set one of the existing values as the default:

[image: Subscriber setting default for managed global picklist value set]

Another example where the managed package set the default to "Pending" and I could switch it to another:

[image: Subscriber switch default for managed global picklist value set]

This was tested on a scratch org with the managed package installed (not pushed metadata).

Comment: A perfect answer Phil. Thank-you!